# How can i get android cellular data usage in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter

I was building an android app using flutter.
and I can not find a plugin to get android cellular data usage.
please someone help me!

Answer (score 0):

Download the `connectivity` from package https://pub.dev/  and after done the get `phpspec.yaml`  file.

Follow this steps.

Add the Data Visualisation Package

The next step is to add the data visualisation package. Flutter stores all of its dependency information in a file called `pubspec.yaml`. For familiarity, you can think of it as a `package.json` file or a pom file.

```
    dependencies:
 flutter:
   sdk: flutter
 charts_flutter: ^0.5.0
```

Comment: I think connectivity package is used to check the current status of the device internet connectivity. what I want to do is to get the total device internet usage (is it 1GB ... or above) not the connectivity state.

Comment: This might be helpful: https://pub.dev/packages/app_usage

Answer (score 0):

I'm using flutter cell_info right now.

https://pub.dev/packages/cell_info

it works fine until I tested 5G (NR) samples and notices  a "null-pointer" bug so I downloaded the plugin from the pub-cache and fixated it by myself

Answer (score 0):

abel. i'm trying to add this exact function to the app i'm building on flutterflow at the moment. the function of getting the amount of internet data a device has used, so each person can know how much data they have used so far.so i came across this your question after searching the internet a lot. i hope you later got through to it. and i'm hoping that in the spirit of the nyou will be willing to show me how you did it so i can do in my app as well. my email address is cronytelcom@gmail.com. i awaits your reply.